# How to make JWM work in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, window-manager, session

I have installed the JWM on Ubuntu 12.04 via the Software Centre, but it doesn't work. When I choose the JWM session from LightDM, it only shows a black screen.

It worked when I had another computer with Ubuntu 11.10, where I had the same problem after the JWM installation. But once, by chance, I chose to start JWM from a Fluxbox session. And after that, i was able to start JWM also from LightDM.

But this solution does not work for me on Ubuntu 12.04. JWM never starts.

Answer (score 0):

You need a .jwmrc file in your ~/ (home directory)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=174188

has a few examples.  Keep in mind the WHOLE interface must be configured by hand. You actually had successfully logged into the JWM, but with no config there was not even a panel or menu, etc....  You can also download the .jwmrc file from puppy linux (I really like his setup).  You always have to manually add programs to your menu file (unless something has changed in the past couple years) Enjoy!